# Why did Haruma Yamazaki become the student council president?

Tags: yamada-and-the-7-witches

In the last episode, Haruma Yamazaki finally allowed Yamada-kun to continue his plan because he wanted to know why he became the student council president. Nevertheless, after the wish was granted, the reason why he became the president is still not clear to me - did I miss anything, or is the reason still unrevealed at this point?

Comment: Most probably, the reason was revealed to him, and he decided not to share.

Comment: My understanding is that he became student council president to protect the Supernatural Club from being disbanded. Unfortunately, the side effect of getting his wish granted was losing his memory of having been in the club, somewhat defeating the purpose.

Comment: @ConMan That's a nice conclusion however, i needed proofs  that's why i posted this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heads up. Spoiler from the manga.

> Haruma Yamazaki became the president of the student council to save the Supernatural Studies Club from being abolished. Because only he and Leona Miyamura are the members of the club.

Source: Chapter 84

Comment: Hey there, welcome to A&M. I removed the website you were referring to as it is [not a legal provider](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923). Ps, you can mark spoilers using >! this will hide the text.

Comment: Okay, i'll take note of that. Thank you! @Dimitrimx

Comment: This sounds exactly like @Coman 's theory, it is therefore correct.